How to set an image as MS excel background which persists while printing/saving as PDF?
I am looking for something like the following. The only issue is that while saving the workbook as PDF or printing, the background doesn't stay. Only white background is kept. Is there a way to keep the image as excel workbook background? If this needs separate tool(s) also, it's fine as long as the need matches.


@KJ How did you do? Can you tell the steps to recreate it?

@R.Medhi, just type in watermark in the excel search box. it should tell you the steps.

To replace the "Background" the image needs to become the Page header backdrop e.g. a "watermark".

